# Code for project euler number 67 getting wrong answer

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve Project Euler number 67 and my code which worked for problem 18 won't work, I ended up with a larger (7320) than expected (7273) answer.

I can't figure out what went wrong, and what I should change about my code to fix it.

```
numbers =[
[59],
#...
]

sums = [
[59],
#...
]

#Adding the first two lines as I couldnt get them to work within the 
#main algorithm

i = 0
x = 1
for y in range(0, len(numbers[x])):
    for a in range(0, len(numbers[x - 1])):
        temp1 = numbers[i][a] + numbers[x][y]
        sums[x].append(temp1)
        print(sums)


#The code basically just splits the trianglet into smaller triangles 
#and adds them up going through the whole line

for x in range(1, len(sums) - 1):


#The bad array is used to store the sums which are smaller when two 
#triangles overlap

    bad = []


#Calculates the sums of the small triangles and puts them into a 2d 
#array of the same size as the one which has all the numbers

    for y in range(0, len(sums[x])):
        temp1 = sums[x][y] + numbers[x + 1][y]
        sums[x + 1].append(temp1)
        temp1 = sums[x][y] + numbers[x + 1][y + 1]
        sums[x + 1].append(temp1)


#This is where the 'bad' array comes into play, it checks overlapping 
#triangles and takes out the smaller sum

    for i in range(1, len(sums[x + 1]) - 2, 2):
        if sums[x + 1][i] >= sums[x + 1][i + 1]:
            a = sums[x + 1][i + 1]
            bad.append(a)
        if sums[x + 1][i + 1] > sums[x + 1][i]:
            a = sums[x + 1][i]
            bad.append(a)

#Here it removes all the 'bad' sums from the final array
    for y in range(0, len(bad)):
        for z in range(0, len(sums[x + 1]) - 1):
            if sums[x + 1][z] == bad[y]:
                sums[x + 1].pop(z)
                break

#Here it print the maximum possible sum once it has reached the bottom triangle
maximum = 0
for x in range(0, len(sums[-1])):
    if sums[-1][x] > maximum:
        maximum = sums[-1][x]
        
print(maximum)
```

Below I attatched the text file with the 'numbers' and 'sums' arrays as they would take up a lot of space if I pasted them here.

[Link to arrays used](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oct8IteNQ_0t8A7aWT9Nk3QDBrqOUSEtJs70vJp70sc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear in the post, what can I change to fix it, and what went wrong? @mkrieger1

Comment: Why did you expect that the code that solves problem 18 also works for problem 67?

Comment: Since they are connected it says so on the page itself. https://projecteuler.net/problem=18

Comment: Well it stated - "However, Problem 67, is the same challenge with a triangle containing one-hundred rows; it cannot be solved by brute force, and requires a clever method! "  - thinking to work bottom up may help.

Comment: Yes @DanielHao I could try that, but there isn't only one correct answer, I want to see how I can get my code to work

Comment: @TomKarzes the code runs fast, give an answer instantly there are no performance issues. Its not brute force, or so I would like to consider as it is fast.

Comment: @DSazykin How are you getting the raw triangle data into your program?  Do you have code that reads their data file and creates your lists from it?  Or are did you manually copy the data into your code?  If the latter, are you certain the data is correct?

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes I have the raw triangle data, I took it directly from the website, and when using someone else's code with my numbers it works.

Comment: I copied the triangle from this website since I didn't want to format it myself. https://github.com/nayuki/Project-Euler-solutions/blob/master/python/p067.py?ts=4

Comment: @TomKarzes, no sums is blank at first but of the same size as numbers, only the first row is the same as it contains the sums of the smaller triangles. The code is complete other than the arrays which I have linked, if you replace the placeholder arrays with the correct ones it should run with no problem.

Comment: @TomKarzes I would have added the numbers for the number 18 problem but that wouldn't help as that code works.

Comment: @DSazykin Ok, I ran your code and got 7320, as you reported.  And it should be 7273.  I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @DSazykin Ok, I finally finished analyzing the code.  I've posted an explanation of the problem, and the fix, as an answer.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @TomKarzes thank you your solution worked, I didn't consider what you said happened when making the code, since at first, I had it remove the 'bad' sum instantly which created problems as the array was smaller and led to the wrong numbers being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at the posted algorithm and I know what the problem is.  When generating a new row of sums, it does it in multiple passes:  First it creates a new double-width row that includes the sums from all parents.  Then it creates a list of the smaller of each conflicting pair.  Finally, it tries to remove the values from that list, producing the final row.

The problem with this is that those "bad" values must be removed from specific positions in the row, but it isn't taking this into account and is removing the first instance of each "bad" value in the row.  This sometimes results in "good" values being removed, leaving the "bad" value.

Here's a simple example that demonstrates this:

```
numbers = [
       [1],
      [2, 1],
     [1, 2, 1],
    [2, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

The largest sum through this triangle is `6`, but the posted code incorrectly gives `7`.  If you look at the `sums` produced by the posted code, they are:

```
       [1]
      [3, 2]
     [5, 4, 3]
    [7, 6, 5, 4]
```

But they should be:

```
       [1]
      [3, 2]
     [4, 5, 3]
    [6, 6, 6, 4]
```

We can now see how this happens.  When generating the third row of sums, the posted code first creates all pairs of sums:

```
    [4, 5, 4, 3]
```

It then creates the "bad" list, which is:

```
    [4]
```

It should remove the second `4` from the list, which would produce the correct row value:

```
    [4, 5, 3]
```

But it instead removes the first `4` it finds, producing the incorrect row list:

```
     [5, 4, 3]
```

This could be fixed by constraining the values that are considered when processing each element from the "bad" list.  But none of that is really necessary.  Instead, it's much simpler to just select the desired values while the row is being generated, eliminating the need for the "bad" list.  The entire `x` loop then looks like this:

```
for x in range(1, len(sums) - 1):
    for y in range(0, len(sums[x])):
        temp1 = sums[x][y] + numbers[x + 1][y]
        if y == 0:
            sums[x + 1].append(temp1)
        elif temp1 > sums[x + 1][-1]:
            sums[x + 1][-1] = temp1

        temp1 = sums[x][y] + numbers[x + 1][y + 1]
        sums[x + 1].append(temp1)
```

This is all that's needed for the `x` loop.  With this fix, it correctly produces `7273` for the original data.